# PHP class returning JSON but doesn't work with AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, json, oop, class

I have an ajax call...

```
        $(function(){
        $('#registerUser').submit(function() {

           $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://www.mysite.co.uk/path/register/add_user.php',
                  type: 'post',
                  data: form.serialize(),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  crossDomain : true,
                  timeout: 5000,

                  success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg.name);
                  },

                  error: function(){
                    alert('There was an error loading the data.');
                  }
                  });
          });
      });
```

this all works fine when I echo out a json object in the PHP file. However when echoing it out using my class it echos out on the page but doesn't work when used with the ajax function - nothing gets returned.

Worth saying I'm a noob to OOP. The object I'm trying to return is just a simple object irrelevant to the function simply for testing purposes.

```
<?php

include('../config/.db.php');
include('../config/headers.php');

$firstName = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

class user{
    public $returnArray;
    public function addUser($firstName, $surname, $email, $password, $mysqli){

    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");   
    $stmt -> bind_param("ssss", $firstName, $surname, $email, $password);   
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);
    $stmt -> fetch();
    $stmt -> close();

    $array = array('name'=>'andre');
    $this->returnArray = json_encode($array);  
    }
}

$user = new user;
$user->addUser($firstName, $surname, $email, $password, $mysqli);
echo $user->returnArray;
?>
```

request/response

```
POST /intheloop/register/add_user.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.co.uk
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
name:a
surname:a
email:a
password:a
password2:a
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Jan 2013 20:51:36 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.15
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=75
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Are the AJAX and PHP on same domain?

Comment: No. Are you getting at using the sever ip instead of local host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was the fact that the line

```
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);
```

was messing up the bind variables expected in the result of the query. Because I wasn't retrieving anything with the query there was nothing to assign the variable $result to.

This in turn gave a PHP error messing up the json returned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are violating the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction that's built into browsers and which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests.

You can send AJAX requests only to scripts that are hosted on the same domain as the one used to host your AJAX script. In this case you seem to be attempting to send an AJAX request to `http://www.mysite.co.uk/path/register/add_user.php` but for this to work your javascript file must be hosted on `http://www.mysite.co.uk/`.

There are [`some workarounds`](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) that you might consider. They involve using [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or a server side bridge script on your domain.

Comment: Hey man. I have got cors stuff in place for cross domain requests. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: But does your browser support CORS? Don't forget that older browsers do not support it. CORS is not something you could rely upon if you intend to support older browsers.

Comment: Great then this should work. Can't see anything wrong with your code. Try checking your javascript console for potential errors. Also inspect the `Network` tab to see if the request is actually made and what did the server respond to it.

Comment: The request sends through all the data fine and the response doesn't seem to send any variables back at all :s

Comment: Can you see the request in the Network tab? How do you know that it is not returning anything. Use FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar where you will be able to see whether your AJAX request is being sent to the server and what does the server respond to it precisely. Without this information it would be hard to help you.

Comment: It's worth saying again that when I echo the object outside of the class it works fine.

Comment: Could you show the JSON payload returned by your PHP script? I can't see it in the response (you have shown only the headers).

Comment: I feel like such a fool. The php is returning an error which is messing up the expected json result. Basically It's not grabbing the variables for the expected parameters properly so throwing a wobbly! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

If your AJAX call does not request data from same domain it will then not work, thats a security which browsers have against misuse of AJAX. Therefore in order to make it work cross domain one of the things that you can do is issue a CORS header from your PHP script.

You can add this to your PHP file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This will then indicate browsers that they can accept this ajax call and data transfer and your script will work then.

Comment: Hey man. I have got cors stuff in place for cross domain requests. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to add this to give the output a proper mime-type, put it 1 line above the 'echo':

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```